# Type mismatch in for loop including tests of worksheet cell values

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I am receiving a type mismatch error in my VBA macro.  Here is the essential part of my code:

```
Public Function CalculateSum(codes As Collection, ws As Worksheet) As Double

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Worksheet is necessery")
    Exit Function
End If


Dim balanceColumnIndex, codesCulumnIndex As Integer
Dim searchStartRow, searchEndRow As Integer
balanceColumnIndex = 17
codesColumnIndex = 4
searchStartRow = 7
searchEndRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, codesColumnIndex).End(xlUp).Row

Dim result As Double
result = 0#

For counter = searchStartRow To searchEndRow
    If Len(ws.Cells(counter, codesColumnIndex)) > 0 And Len(ws.Cells(counter, balanceColumnIndex)) > 0 And _
    IsNumeric(ws.Cells(counter, codesColumnIndex).Value) And IsNumeric(ws.Cells(counter, balanceColumnIndex).Value) Then
        If Contains(codes, CLng(ws.Cells(counter, codesColumnIndex).Value)) Then
            result = result + ws.Cells(counter, balanceColumnIndex).Value
            ''' ^^^ This line throws a type-mismatch error
        End If
    End If
Next counter


CalculateSum = result

ErrorHandler:
Debug.Print ("counter: " & counter & "\ncode: " & ws.Cells(counter, codesColumnIndex).Value & "\namount: " & ws.Cells(counter, balanceColumnIndex).Value)

End Function
```

Now what happens is that a type-mismatch error occures on the line where current row balance is added to `result` even though:

- searchEndRow equals 129, and somehow counter equals 130
- cells under current address are empty, yet somehow they pass test for length and numeric values (I stopped to debug at this point, `IsNumeric(ws.Cells(counter, codesColumnIndex).Value)` returns `true`!

Now I am simply confused and I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: The variable used in a `for ... to ...` will always be the limit + 1 after the loop. That is normal.

Comment: `Cells.Value` returns a variant. If it is empty, then it can be casted as a number (0) and thus is numeric. Again, this is normal.

Comment: @litelite but why is it passing Len(ws.Cells(counter,codesColumnIndex))>0 test?

Comment: Are you sure the value is actually empty? maybe it's zero and you have [`DisplayZeros`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839216.aspx)  set to `False`?

Comment: Did you make sure that the `Len` returns >0? (You only said that you checked the `IsNumeric` part)

Comment: @litelite Yeah, I am positive, double checked

Comment: Two thoughts: **(1)** instead of `Len(Cells(...))`, try `Len(CStr(Cells(...).Value))` to make sure you are checking strings.  **(2)** Remember that VBA doesn't have short-circuit evaluation, so the `IsNumeric` tests in your `If` statement will happen regardless of what the `Len` tests say.  I don't think that's your problem, but it might trip you up down the line.  I use nested `If` statements to do manually what I wish VBA would do for me ;) .

Comment: Also, what is the actual error?  Is it an exception that stops the macro from running, or is it that you get a value you don't expect, or something else?

Comment: And one more question!  Which `Contains` implementation are you using?  VBA collections don't take `Long` values as keys, but only as indices, per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: @cxw Looks like Len(Cstr()) is working. The biggest problem is errors is thrown on clients computer and on mine's not (any idea why that is happening?). The exception was type mismatch from the line where result is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have noted, `Cells(...).Value` is a `Variant`.  This means that operators may not apply to `.Value` the way you expect.  For tests using `Len` or other string operations, expressly convert to a string.  For example, instead of `Len(ws.Cells(...))`, try `Len(CStr(ws.Cells(...).Value))`.  That way you will know that `Len` is giving you the result you expect.

Similarly, where you add to `result`, use `result = result + CDbl(ws.Cells(...).Value)` to make sure you are adding `Double` values together.

To answer your question regarding errors that happen differently on different computers, what I have most often experienced is that it is the specific data in question.  As one of the commenters pointed out, `Empty` is indeed numeric since it implicitly converts to `0`!  As a result, `IsNumeric(Empty)` is `True`.  Using `CStr` guards against that in your code because `IsNumeric(CStr(Empty)) = IsNumeric("") = False`.  Using `IsNumeric(CStr(...))` prevents you from trying to add `0# + ""`, which is a type mismatch.  So perhaps the user has an empty cell that you don't have in your test data, and that's causing the problem.  That's not the only possibility, just the one I have encountered most.